# Cannot run Vagrant installator

Tags: installation, window, vagrant

I download Vagram from the official web page. The download was successs, but when I double click on it to intall it I have no response. There is no error message, it just don´t start the installation. I´m using Windows Vista.

I tryed to open it with double click and with right button install. I also move the file to other directory, but is still happening the same. I have no clue why is not starting the installation. Any ideas? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

With so little information... my tips:

- Check MD5 (or any hash Vagrant gives you) between you downloaded file and the hosted by server to ensure your downloaded file is ok.
- Check your windows's user have enough privileges to run installations.
- Ctrl + Shift + Esc > Is the installation process running?